# MySQL LIKE clause with variables in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I defined a model and tried to get data from two tables using the `UNION` keyword. Here I used the `LIKE` keyword as a constraint. When I use this query without variables (hard-coded variable values), it works. But it doesn't work with variables. Instead it gives an empty array. What's wrong with it?

```
function searchProf(){
    //$name=$this->input->post('name');
    $name='du';
    $query=$this->db->query("SELECT name FROM users WHERE  name like '%".$name."%' UNION SELECT name FROM children WHERE name like '%".$name."%' ");
    print_r ($query->result());

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `'%".$name."%'` to this `'%$name%'`.

---

```
function searchProf(){
    //$name=$this->input->post('name');
    $name ='du';
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT name FROM users WHERE  name like '%$name%' UNION SELECT name FROM children WHERE name like '%$name%' ");
    print_r ($query->result());    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use active record base or SQL binding to your SQL queries. Otherwise you have to face for SQL Injections.

`

```
function searchProf(){
    $name ='du';
    $sql = "SELECT name FROM users WHERE  name like ? UNION SELECT name FROM children WHERE name like ? ";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql,array('%'.$name.'%','%'.$name.'%'));
    print_r ($query->result());     
}
```